How can I make French doors more secure?
We have a pair of beautiful French doors for our front door, but we're worried they're not as secure against burglary as they might be. Obviously there's no such thing as perfectly secure, but are there steps I can take to make them better?
I was looking at the "Door Armor" products and various security films that can be applied to the glass (I assume the fake lead on the existing glass has no structural value).
We've already got cameras and sensors and even considering "Deep Sentinel" security services and I recognize physical security is a little bit futile (the house has ground floor windows that aren't secure either) but it might give a bit of peace of mind.
How can I make these doors more secure?




Bad people do not like light.  So motion sensor lights will help a bit.  Any window is like a open hole/door, unless special glass(amour)/security bars are used.  Might look icky on your doors.  Lights will scare most away.  Lights plus cameras will scare away a few extra.  What is left, do not be at home.

They do look nice, in a FL Wright style, it seems, and I hesitate to suggest covering with polycarbonate -- not sure it could be done in a way that is both secure and preserves looks.

Asking us how to solve a problem on one's house isn't opinion based. It's a DIY question and "how do I fix this" is a common theme here. Shouldn't have been closed based on opinion. Vote to re-open.

Is the question about securing the doors themselves, or the windows in particular?  I'm aware that the windows are part of the doors, but the solutions may be different.

To keep someone from simply breaking the glass and reaching an arm through to unlock the door, you need to have the edge of the glass opening more than an arm's length away from the inside lock controls. That glass is not only close enough for a mere hand to reach through to turn the locks, but it is big enough to break out and walk through without unlocking the door. Even security bars would not prevent someone breaking the glass close to the knobs and putting a hand through to the locks.
If you take the existing moldings off the inside of the doors, attach half-inch (12mm) thick clear plastic plates behind the decorative glass to the door body/frame, and surround the plastic with appropriate molding, then you may be able to keep the see-through look while making it harder to get through the opening.
Gate slide bolts pointing up and down on the door that doesn't have the knobs and fixing into the floor and beefy brackets above the top of the door will help against merely smashing through the doorway. (No doubt there is such hardware present already, but thicker could help be better.)
Since battery-powered angle grinders are a thing now, and one need only slice through the lock bolts at the crack between the doors, all locks are only security theatre nowadays and serve only to keep honest people more honest. Use other security concepts to make it harder for a burglar to think this is a decent way to get into the house. Lots of hard-to-reach lights, no plants or trees between this doorway and places people could see who's standing there, alarms, etc, can make a burglar balance the minute they'd be grinding at the bolts against whether they'll be seen and have the police called on them.
